# Unable to use Bootstrap in project using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, bootstrap-4, visual-studio-2019, libman

I have installed the Bootstrap using LibMan in Visual Studio with jQuery, and have added its reference in the `_layout.cshtml` file, but it is not working—meaning it is still showing content in the default browser style. Can you please help me find the issue?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @*// Bootstrap Libraries*@
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/css/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @* Jquery Libs *@
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>

    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      @RenderBody()
    </div>
      @if (IsSectionDefined("Scripts"))
      {
        @RenderSection("Scripts", required: true)
      }
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @software-student, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you open your browser's debugging console, and look at e.g. the _Network_ tab, can you confirm that the `bootstrap.css` file is being downloaded correctly, and not getting a 404? Are you certain the file has been downloaded and correctly placed in the `/lib/bootstrap/css/` folder?

Comment: I just resolve my issue thank you Dear @JeremyCaney

Comment: @SoftwareStudent can you post how you resolved it as an answer in case someone else encounters a similar issue?

Comment: Yes just added the environment to it and resolved.